# Listening horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript has the ability to listen scrolling on the fly (scrollTop(); isn't it). But is there a function to listen where i've scrolled if i'm doing it horizontally?

I have a div of images, what can be scrolled horizontally ( See: http://jsfiddle.net/j5q1b8x9/).

```
.scroll-container {
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
```

}

And what I want to do is this that when I scroll to the right, the red box will move to the left and vice a versa. I've tried the scrollLeft(); , but it fires itself when i've reached the end of my images, so it isn't listening the coordinates on the fly.

Bonus, it's possible to implement this kind of function to each of the images, by using the foreach path? I.e. if I scroll one image from the viewport from left to right, the red box will move from right to left, and when a new image pops to the viewport, the jazz begins again, for the new image.

Any ideas what should I test out to make the red box move as a mirror when scrolling from left to right?

Comment: do you want a red box for each image that moves?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question this works [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hkaf3hny/2/)

```
var container = $(".scroll-container");
var box= $(".test-div");
var scrollX =container.scrollLeft();
container.scroll(function(){
var delta =container.scrollLeft() - scrollX; // direction < 0 From left to right
scrollX =container.scrollLeft();
if (delta<0)

    box.css({left:0, right:'auto'});  
else
    box.css({left:'auto', right:0});
```

});

Comment: Well, almost. What i think that if you scroll right 40px, then the box on the right, will scroll -40px to the left etc.